# Obtendo vários valores de uma String

Tags: .net, string, visual-basic-6

Tem algum jeito de obter os argumentos como no exemplo abaixo, em variável separada? Estou criando uma linguagem, e esse é um bloco exemplo:

```
for 0 to 250 step 50
^^^ ^ ^^ ^^^ ^^^^ ^^
```

Daí eu usei o método `String.Split(" ")` e funcionou, porém a dúvida é, e se quiser colocar um campo que tem espaços, exemplo:

```
if "esse campo tem espaços" = true
^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^
```

mas ta retornando assim:

```
if "esse campo tem espaços" = true
^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^
```

Invés de obter numa array assim:

```
if
esse campo tem espaços
=
true
```

ele ta separando o que ta no campo também, daí ta ficando assim:

```
if
esse
campo
tem 
espaços
=
true
```

e da conflito... Tem algum jeito de obter os valores dentro do campo sem ocorrer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez não seja possível usar o [método `String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para esse propósito, expressões regulares podem vir a cair bem neste caso, use o [método `Regex.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```c
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
'

Function ExtrairBlocos(ByVal texto As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim blocos As New List(Of String)
    blocos = Regex.Split(texto, "(""[^""]*""|\s+)").ToList()
    blocos.RemoveAll(Function(bloco) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bloco))
    Return blocos
End Function
```

E para utilizar, faça:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim texto As String = "if ""esse campo tem espaços"" = true"
    Dim blocos As New List(Of String)
    blocos = ExtrairBlocos(texto)

    For Each bloco As String In blocos
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", bloco)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvjIsA)